# How to Add video to the collection view cell and how to customize the video view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I working on the app like `Instagram`.In that I record the video using `Avcapture` session by following this link  https://github.com/shu223/SlowMotionVideoRecorder and I used it as third party library.

now, I want pass the video and play it in the `CollectionViewCell` and the `CollectionViewCell` contains another 15 images

```
NSString *videostring=[recordedFile absoluteString];
             NSLog(@"%@",videostring);

              NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: videostring];
             NSString *videoPath = [videoURL path];
             UIStoryboard *storybord=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

             shareViewController   *shareview=[storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"share"];
             [self presentViewController:shareview animated:YES completion:nil];
             //shareview.finalvideourl=videoURL;
             shareview.videooutputstring=videoPath;
```

To pass this to the next screen i am using the ns notification center,In the next screen I am using

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"sharevideooutputstring" object:_videooutputstring];
```

How to add this in the `CollectionViewCell`.I am new to the iOS,please help  out to solve this problem.example link or code  is appreciated.

```
-(void)sharevideooutputstring:(NSNotification*)notification
{

NSString *finalstring=notification.object;
[self.collection reloadData];
_collection.delegate=self;
_collection.dataSource=self;


}
```

Comment: @suraj thank you do you know the solution

Comment: or else how to play the recent recored video from the device document directory in the collection view